# Python MQTT connection to Azure Iot Hub

Tags: python, azure, mqtt, azure-iot-hub

I want to connect to Azure Iot Hub, with Python MQTT.

An username and SAS token is required by Iot Hub. This is my code:

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print("Connected with result code "+str(rc))
    client.subscribe("$SYS/#")

def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    print(msg.topic+" "+str(msg.payload))

client = mqtt.Client()
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_message = on_message

client.username_pw_set("myHub.azure-devices.net/device1", "mySASToken")

client.connect("myHub.azure-devices.net", 1883, 60)

client.loop_forever()
```

But after running for a while, this exception is thrown:

TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

Does somebody know why I can't connect to the Iot Hub?

Comment: Is it definitely using port 1883, not port 8883 (which is the TLS version)?

Comment: Please try this one. It worked for me.
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57243449/connecting-with-m2mqtt-paho-python-client-to-azure-iot-hub/66741952#66741952](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57243449/connecting-with-m2mqtt-paho-python-client-to-azure-iot-hub/66741952#66741952)

Answer (score 3):

There is now an official Python SDK to connect devices to Azure IoT Hub:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdks/tree/master/python/device

[This sample](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdks/blob/master/python/device/samples/iothub_client_sample_mqtt.py) demonstrates how to connect using the MQTT protocol.

Basically, here's how it works:

1. create a device client and specifies MQTT for the protocol
2. set the callback that will be called when a message is received
3. use send_event_async to send messages to your Azure IoT Hub instance.

```py
from iothub_client import *

def send_confirmation_callback(message, result, userContext):
    print "Confirmation[%d] received for message with result = %s" % (userContext, result)

def receive_message_callback(message, counter):
    buffer = message.get_bytearray()
    size = len(buffer)
    print "Received Message"
    print "    Data: <<<%s>>> & Size=%d" % (buffer[:size], size)
    return IoTHubMessageDispositionResult.ACCEPTED

iotHubClient = IoTHubClient(connectionString, IoTHubTransportProvider.MQTT)
iotHubClient.set_message_callback(receive_message_callback, 0)
iotHubClient.send_event_async(message, send_confirmation_callback, 0)
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11937174)

Comment: thanks for the feedback. i added the gist of the code sample.

Answer (score 2):

As @FarukCelik said, there was no Azure IoT SDK for Python.

However, per my experience, I think there are four practicable ways using the existing SDK for Azure IoTHub in Python.

1. Using Azure IoT SDK for C to extending Python, you can try to refer to https://docs.python.org/2/extending/extending.html to implement it.
2. Using Azure IoT SDK for Java as Jython package imported, you can try to refer to http://www.jython.org/jythonbook/en/1.0/JythonAndJavaIntegration.html to know how to do it.
3. The similar to the second way, integrating IronPython with Azure IoT SDK for C#/.Net, please refer to http://ironpython.net/documentation/dotnet/.
4. The Azure IoT SDK for NodeJS support MQTT via the same Eclipse project `Paho` for JavaScript Client, so I think you can try to refer to the source code of [Azure NodeJS IoT SDK on GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdks/tree/master/node) to know how to correctly using [paho Python client](https://www.eclipse.org/paho/clients/python/) for Azure IoTHub.

Meanwhile, there is a unoffical Python library for Azure IoTHub Device on GitHub https://github.com/bechynsky/AzureIoTDeviceClientPY. That you can concern about this project repository, but it's still on the deveploment stage by now.

Hope it helps. Best Regards.

Comment: Thank you for replying with an useful answer. I will go and look into Ironpython.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to use paho (mosquitto) to connect to the Azure IoT Hub over standard MQTT:

```
from paho.mqtt import client as mqtt


def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print "Connected with result code: %s" % rc
    client.subscribe("devices/<YOUR DEVICE ID>/messages/devicebound/#")


def on_disconnect(client, userdata, rc):
    print "Disconnected with result code: %s" % rc


def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    print " - ".join((msg.topic, str(msg.payload)))
    # Do this only if you want to send a reply message every time you receive one
    client.publish("devices/<YOUR DEVICE ID>/messages/events", "REPLY", qos=1)


def on_publish(client, userdata, mid):
    print "Sent message"


client = mqtt.Client(cleint_id=<YOUR DEVICE ID>, protocol=mqtt.MQTTv311)
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_disconnect = on_disconnect
client.on_message = on_message
client.on_publish = on_publish
client.username_pw_set(username="<YOUR NAMESPACE>.azure-devices.net/<YOUR DEVICE ID>",
                       password="<YOUR SHARED ACCESS SIGNATURE FOR THE DEVICE>")
client.tls_insecure_set(True) # You can also set the proper certificate using client.tls_set()
client.connect("<YOUR NAMESPACE>.azure-devices.net", port=8883)
client.loop_forever()
```

Answer (score -1):

Referring to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/iot-hub-sdks-summary/ Azure IoT SDK does not contain Pyhon "yet". This is already raised by other customers in https://feedback.azure.com/forums/321918-azure-iot . (Direct link : https://feedback.azure.com/forums/321918-azure-iot/suggestions/10522101-add-python-client-sdk).

Comment: It is true, there is no Python SDK at this moment. But it should be possible to send message's to Iot Hub with Python, by using the MQTT protocol directly.