# Python and Azure Iot Hub

Tags: python, azure, mqtt, azure-iot-hub

I have Python code running on a Raspberry Pi. I need to connect to Azure Iot Hub from my Python code by using plain MQTT protocol.

I cannot use the libraries for connecting to Iot Hub. I am looking for a way to do this in Python and plain MQTT.

Does anyone know how this can be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refer to my post for the other thread [Python MQTT connection to Azure Iot Hub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35452072/python-mqtt-connection-to-azure-iot-hub).

As a RaspberryPi fan, I suggest that you can try to extend Python with Azure IoT SDK for C, please see https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/iot-hub-device-sdk-c-intro/ and https://docs.python.org/2/extending/extending.html.

The other choice is that using the Azure IoT SDK for NodeJS to create a server as proxy for listening Python push messages and forwarding to Azure IoTHub, please see https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdks/tree/master/node/device. And according to the version of your Respberry Pi, you need to download the suitable nodejs runtime as below from the nodejs offical website https://nodejs.org/en/download/ or via using `sudo apt-get install nodejs` on the Raspbian OS.

1. Respberry Pi: [ARMv6](https://nodejs.org/dist/v4.3.1/node-v4.3.1-linux-armv6l.tar.xz)
2. Respberry Pi 2: [ARMv7](https://nodejs.org/dist/v4.3.1/node-v4.3.1-linux-armv7l.tar.xz)

Otherwise, the simple way for sending messages from device to Azure IoTHub on Respberry PI is that using the [Device Messaging REST APIs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt590785.aspx) in Python.

Hope it helps. Best Regards.

Comment: Hi Peter Pan. Thank you again for replying. I will look into your suggestions. And hopefully find a way to connect Python with IOT Hub

Comment: With HTTP REST I am able to send messages to IOT Hub. Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by plain MQTT protocol.

The main implementation of MQTT is Python is the Paho one:
https://eclipse.org/paho/clients/python/

Have you tried that?

I have not used the Azure Iot Hub, but I would presume that it is possible to get a MQTT hostname, port, username and password, which would then be used to connect to it?

nick.

Comment: Hello Nick, Yes I tried Paho. But I can't make a connection, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

The Python SDK for Azure IoT Hub is now here: https://github.com/azure/azure-iot-sdk-python and natively supports MQTT

Answer (score -1):

The Python SDK for Azure IoT Hub has been released and should work to connect a Raspberry Pi to Azure IoT Hub.

See here:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdks/tree/master/python/device