# Python paho-MQTT connection with azure IoT-Hub

Tags: python, azure, mqtt, mosquitto, azure-iot-hub

I am trying to connect with Azure IoT-Hub with MQTT and send and receive messages.

I am following the official documentation given [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/iot-hub-mqtt-support/)

But it always get disconnected with result code: 1, though it never goes inside the on_connect function.
But if I try to publish it outside the functions (The commented out line after connection string), it goes inside the on_publish method.

The deivce I am using here is a simulated device I created in the Azure IoT Suite

Here is the code I am using

```
from paho.mqtt import client as mqtt


def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print "Connected with result code: %s" % rc
    client.subscribe("devices/MyTestDevice02/messages/devicebound/#")
    client.publish("devices/MyTestDevice02/messages/events", "Hello World!")


def on_disconnect(client, userdata, rc):
    print "Disconnected with result code: %s" % rc


def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    print " - ".join((msg.topic, str(msg.payload)))
    client.publish("devices/MyTestDevice02/messages/events", "REPLY", qos=1)


def on_publish(client, userdata, mid):
    print "Sent message"


client = mqtt.Client("MyTestDevice02", mqtt.MQTTv311)
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_disconnect = on_disconnect
client.on_message = on_message
client.on_publish = on_publish
client.username_pw_set(username="USERNAME.azure-devices.net/MyTestDevice02",
                       password="SharedAccessSignature=SharedAccessSignature sr=USERNAME.azure-devices.net%2fdevices%2fMyTestDevice02&sig=xxxxxx5rRr7c%3d&se=1492318301")
client.tls_insecure_set(True) # You can also set the proper certificate using client.tls_set()
client.connect("USERNAME.azure-devices.net", port=8883)
#client.publish("devices/MyTestDevice02/messages/events", "Hello World!")
client.loop_forever()
```

Any help is appreciated.
And I dont want to use the sdk which is why I am trying to publish it directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally resolved the issue.
It was the problem with setting tls and I wasn't able to do that in python for some reason, so I used C# ,

Here is a simple version of it.

```
client = new MqttClient("MyTestHub.azure-devices.net", 8883, true, MqttSslProtocols.TLSv1_0, null, null);
byte code = client.Connect("MyDevice1", "MyTestHub.azure-devices.net/MyDevice123","Use My SAS token");
ushort msgId = client.Publish("devices/MyDevice1/messages/events/", Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Test Message"), 1, false);
```

I used [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/M2Mqtt/) library for MQTT.

Answer (score 2):

You've not enabled TLS - you'll need to use `tls_set()` to pass the CA certificates to trust. Using `tls_insecure_set()` on its own does nothing.

Comment: Thank you, but I am not able find the CA certificates.
Can you please walk me through the process, or may be link explaining it.

Comment: I have generated and associated the certificate with my azure subscription follwing this [link](https://www.veritas.com/support/en_US/article.TECH217325)

And in the tls_set() i have given the path to the location of certificate in my local machine and it is throwing the error "certificate verification failed"

Answer (score -1):

There is a similiar thread from MS TechNet https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0c2cc683-c50f-428c-90ca-eeff132ba5e9/python-azure-iot-hub-mqtt-direct-with-basic-library?forum=windowsazuredevelopment.

I suggest that you can try to use other support languages for Azure IoTHub, such as Node.js or Java.

Meanwhile, you can refer to my sugguestion for using Azure IoTHub with Python in the SO thread [Python MQTT connection to Azure Iot Hub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35452072/python-mqtt-connection-to-azure-iot-hub) via extending Python with other support languages.

Any concern, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: Thank you, but the first link does not have any answer for the question, and in the second you are suggesting to use the SDK, which I dont want to as the SDK is heavy and I want to load the code to a very light weight machine, like something which has very limited memory.

Azure has released SDK for python and I am able to connect and send data using it in python. Unfortunately that's not a viable option for me.

Comment: @aladeen What scenario do you want to suppport? What's your very light weight machine? As a known, some devices have enough memory for using the SDK, such as Raspberry Pi, BeagleBoard, even Intel Edison. However, for Arduino Ethernet or Arduino Yun, I think using HTTP client library or MQTT client library for Arduino  is better for limited memory. Any concern, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: @aladeen For using HTTP REST API, you can refer to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt548492.aspx.

Comment: I am using Arduino Ethernet

Comment: I am using the MQTT client library for adruino, but in general I am not able to connect with the hub as I have explained in my question. Can you please provide any example where they have achieved this using simple MQTT.
Thanks for the effort

Comment: @aladeen I only have [a sample code](https://gist.github.com/bear256/1054b17c422f869775d066e4345840e8) for using REST API in Python to send device-to-cloud message. I don't think Python can be running on Arduino Ethernet. I suggest you can try to use simple HTTP client for C/Arduino.

Comment: Thank You. Yes python cant be run on arduino, but the concept remains the same as in the MQTT part.

Comment: Can I view messages send to the hub in the iot suite ??

Comment: @aladeen It seems that you can retrieve these messages from IoTHub for viewing. Any update?

Comment: @peter-pan-msft Yeah I am able to receive messages in IoTHub send using HTTP, but still no luck with mqtt