# Azure IoT Edge Custom Module doesn't connect to IoT-Hub-Container

Tags: python, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge

My problem is probably the same as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35452072/python-mqtt-connection-to-azure-iot-hub) but I don't understand those fancy big city stackoverflow politics so I don't want to disturb anyone and just ask my own question.

I want to connect my Windows PC as "Edge Device" to my Azure IoT Hub according to the Microsoft Tutorials [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/iot-edge/). Everything works absolutely fine when I only run the "temperatureSensor"-module which comes as an Image on Microsoft repository. The module is run, connects to the hub-container which sends the data to the azure hub.

The next step would be to write custom modules. There is also a tutorial for that on Microsofts site which gives a template for C# and Python that can be modified for any purposes. I tried both example (C# and Python) but only the C#-Version worked without any further problems. But since I am not very proficient in C#, only Python, I need to get that one running as well.

But the Python version fails shortly after downloading the images and starting the containers. The edgeAgent and edgeHub as well as the Mock-"temperatureSensor" modules run without problems as was before. But the custom python module seems not to be able to connect to the hub-container. The docker logs are as follow:

edgeAgent:

```
2018-06-22 10:28:26.062 +00:00 [INF] - Plan execution started for deployment 8
2018-06-22 10:28:26.062 +00:00 [INF] - Executing command: "Command Group: (
  [docker stop -t 10 filterModule]
  [docker start filterModule]
  [Update health stats for module filterModule]
)"
2018-06-22 10:28:26.062 +00:00 [INF] - Executing command: "docker stop -t 10 filterModule"
2018-06-22 10:28:26.063 +00:00 [INF] - Executing command: "docker start filterModule"
2018-06-22 10:28:26.567 +00:00 [INF] - Executing command: "Update health stats for module filterModule"
2018-06-22 10:28:26.567 +00:00 [INF] - Plan execution ended for deployment 8
2018-06-22 10:28:26.872 +00:00 [INF] - Updated reported properties
2018-06-22 10:28:56.975 +00:00 [INF] - HealthRestartPlanner is clearing restart stats for module 'edgeHub' as it has been running healthy for 00:10:00.
2018-06-22 10:28:56.975 +00:00 [INF] - Plan execution started for deployment 8
2018-06-22 10:28:56.975 +00:00 [INF] - Executing command: "Reset health stats for module edgeHub"
2018-06-22 10:28:56.977 +00:00 [INF] - Plan execution ended for deployment 8
2018-06-22 10:28:57.263 +00:00 [INF] - Updated reported properties
2018-06-22 10:29:02.268 +00:00 [INF] - HealthRestartPlanner is clearing restart stats for module 'tempSensor' as it has been running healthy for 00:10:00.
2018-06-22 10:29:02.268 +00:00 [INF] - Plan execution started for deployment 8
2018-06-22 10:29:02.268 +00:00 [INF] - Executing command: "Reset health stats for module tempSensor"
2018-06-22 10:29:02.268 +00:00 [INF] - Plan execution ended for deployment 8
2018-06-22 10:29:02.571 +00:00 [INF] - Updated reported properties
```

edgeHub:

```
2018-06-22 10:26:14.438 +00:00 [INF] - Attempting to connect to IoT Hub for client xxxdevice/filterModule via AMQP over WebSocket...
2018-06-22 10:26:14.439 +00:00 [INF] - New token requested by client xxxdevice/filterModule, but using existing token as it is usable.
2018-06-22 10:26:14.789 +00:00 [INF] - Connected to IoT Hub for client xxxdevice/filterModule via AMQP over WebSocket, with client operation timeout 60000.
2018-06-22 10:26:14.793 +00:00 [INF] - Closed cloud proxy for device xxxdevice/filterModule
2018-06-22 10:26:14.793 +00:00 [INF] - No session state found in store for xxxdevice/filterModule
2018-06-22 10:26:14.793 +00:00 [INF] - New cloud connection created for device xxxdevice/filterModule
2018-06-22 10:26:14.793 +00:00 [INF] - Successfully authenticated device xxxdevice/filterModule
2018-06-22 10:26:14.793 +00:00 [INF] - Successfully generated identity for clientId xxxdevice/filterModule and username xxx-iothub.azure-devices.net/xxxdevice/filterModule/api-version=2016-11-14&DeviceClientType=iothubclient%2f1.1.31%20(native%3b%20Linux%3b%20x86_64)
2018-06-22 10:26:14.793 +00:00 [INF] - ClientAuthenticated, xxxdevice/filterModule, 084e3167
2018-06-22 10:28:26.580 +00:00 [INF] - Attempting to connect to IoT Hub for client xxxdevice/filterModule via AMQP...
2018-06-22 10:29:26.583 +00:00 [INF] - Attempting to connect to IoT Hub for client xxxdevice/filterModule via AMQP over WebSocket...
2018-06-22 10:29:26.584 +00:00 [INF] - New token requested by client xxxdevice/filterModule, but using existing token as it is usable.
2018-06-22 10:29:26.918 +00:00 [INF] - Connected to IoT Hub for client xxxdevice/filterModule via AMQP over WebSocket, with client operation timeout 60000.
2018-06-22 10:29:26.919 +00:00 [INF] - Closed cloud proxy for device xxxdevice/filterModule
2018-06-22 10:29:26.923 +00:00 [INF] - No session state found in store for xxxdevice/filterModule
2018-06-22 10:29:26.923 +00:00 [INF] - New cloud connection created for device xxxdevice/filterModule
2018-06-22 10:29:26.924 +00:00 [INF] - Successfully authenticated device xxxdevice/filterModule
2018-06-22 10:29:26.924 +00:00 [INF] - Successfully generated identity for clientId xxxdevice/filterModule and username xxx-iothub.azure-devices.net/xxxdevice/filterModule/api-version=2016-11-14&DeviceClientType=iothubclient%2f1.1.31%20(native%3b%20Linux%3b%20x86_64)
2018-06-22 10:29:26.924 +00:00 [INF] - ClientAuthenticated, xxxdevice/filterModule, 126cb7eb
2018-06-22 10:31:33.659 +00:00 [ERR] - Module filterModule is not connected
```

filter:

```
Python 2.7.12 (default, Dec  4 2017, 14:50:18)
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609]

IoT Hub Client for Python
Adding TrustedCerts from: /mnt/edgemodule/edge-device-ca.cert.pem
set_option TrustedCerts successful
Starting the IoT Hub Python sample using protocol MQTT...
The sample is now waiting for messages and will indefinitely.  Press Ctrl-C to exit.
Error: Time:Fri Jun 22 10:28:57 2018 File:/usr/sdk/src/c/iothub_client/src/iothubtransport_mqtt_common.c Func:InitializeConnection Line:2003 mqtt_client timed out waiting for CONNACK
```

This is repeated ad infinitum. It seems that the hub does take notice of the filter but and authentication succeeds but access is denied anyway. Could this be a bug in the Python SDK, since as I said it worked perfectly fine with the C#-Version (in the otherwise same scenario). Or is it possible that it is a firewall problem. I don't really think that, because the filter log indicates a MQTT problem. And as far as I understand MQTT only applies to inner-edge-device traffic and not to outgoing traffic (outside docker and the device). So firewalls shouldn't be a problem (?)
The actual problem is apparently a timeout waiting for acknowledgment of the connection by the hub. So either the hub doesn't get the connection request or doesn't reply or the reply is lost somehow.

Thanks for all help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this post I also got the chance to talk to a Microsoft person on a convention. When we tried to replicate the problem it turned out that that whole procedure was changed the day before. Iotedgectl is now a Windows service (as far as I can say before it was "just" a regular process [does that make sense?])

Anyway: the whole iot-edge seems to be overhauled at the moment. So in my experience much will change and I am optimistic that the next time I try the tutorials everything will work just fine. I'm closing this thread.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are trying to run Windows containers on your Windows Edge device.  Python (and C) custom modules on Windows containers are currently not supported. This has to do with the way we store and retrieve keys.  This feature is definitely on the roadmap, although we do not have any ETA at the moment.  There are few ways to get around this:

- You can run on Linux containers
- You can run on Linux machines or VMs
- More language support will be added soon - you can view our progress on module-preview branch for [azure-iot-sdk-node](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-node) and [azure-iot-sdk-java](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-java)

Comment: No I actually did use Linux Containers, only with Docker on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue working with **Linux Containers** on a **Linux Edge Device**. All my modules where written in **Python** except one which is an **Azure Stream Analytics**.

To solve the problem, I had to uninstall azure-iot-edge-runtime-ctl... 
Not a "proper" way of solving it but it worked ! 
Here is my script :

```
sudo pip3 uninstall azure-iot-edge-runtime-ctl
sudo pip3 install azure-iot-edge-runtime-ctl
sudo iotedgectl setup --connection-string "<your connection key>" --auto-cert-gen-force-no-password
sudo iotedgectl login --address <your container registry address> --username <your container registry username> --password <your container registry password>
sudo iotedgectl start
```

I am also interested by a proper way to resolve it if someone has a better idea... ?