# Publish with Python to Azure IoT Hub - Subscribe with C# not working

Tags: c#, python-3.x, publish-subscribe, azure-iot-hub

I publish with M2MQTT Paho Python library on the device as follows:

```
    msg = "POS {} {} {} {} {} {} {}"

    msgtosend=msg.format(tagNum, tagID, x_pos, y_pos, z_pos, qos, unk)
    print(msgtosend)
    # qos=1 - (must be when clean_session is False) 
    mqttinfo=rpiclient.publish("dwm/position", msgtosend, 1) 
    if mqttinfo.rc != 0:
        print("Publishing message with ID {) failed. Error Code={}".format(mqttinfo.mid, mqttinfo.rc))
```

Then, I am trying to read the data in C# application again with M2MQTT C# library (after successful connection to Azure IoT Hub) as follows:

```
    tpc[0] = "devices/MasterTag/messages/devicebound/#";
    tpc[1] = "$iothub/twin/PATCH/properties/desired/#";
    tpc[2] = "$iothub/methods/POST/#";
    tpc[3] = "$iothub/twin/res/#";

    mqttClient.Subscribe(tpc, qosArray);
```

where qosArray has only one item and it is either 0 or 1.
...and yet, I do not get any messages. In fact my callback MqttClient_MqttMsgSubscribed is not called either, which means that subscription was not successful and yet I get no error messages or exceptions...

Comment: I do recommend to read the https://www.hivemq.com/blog/mqtt-client-library-encyclopedia-m2mqtt/ for usage of the M2Mqtt - MQTT Client Library using C#.

Comment: I am familiar. This is not the 1st Broker type I am doing. I have full solution for Mosquitto Broker on Raspi and for Mosquitto on CloudMQTT. It is all about the broker itself and differences in authentication that they use/require. Azure IoT Hub and AWS IoT are simply not clear enough with their documentation and explanation, especially Microsoft that always must be special and better...Like in this case it almost Ph.D how to publish the topic...

Comment: Btw. Azure IoT Hub is *not* a generic communication broker. For your implementation issue: the M2MQTT client is a 3rd party library, the recommended document shows how to subscribe on topic using C# and it doesn't matter where the client is connected. In other words, in your example, the *qosArray* must have 4 items and doesn't depend from Azure IoT Hub, you have to follow an M2MQTT Client APIs, such as my recommended document.

Comment: Are your *rpiclient* (publisher) and *mqttClient* (subscriber) are different devices in the Azure IoT Hub? Note, that the MQTT protocol is a connection oriented protocol and the Azure IoT Hub doesn't support multiple MQTT connections for the same *deviceId* within the same iot hub namespace. In other words, the second connection will drop the first one.

Comment: My publisher is M2MQTT Paho Python running on Raspi which take data from a device via serial and tries to push it to Azure IoT Hub (or other service of choice). The subscriber is full blown C# application running on Win10 laptop. I have a separate python script on Raspi at this point that acts as a publisher for each of the big services (CloudMQTT working, Azure IoT Hub and AWS IoT not yet, and Google later). My C# application hosts a number of Mqtt clients (on demand) each connecting to a different service if needed, simultaneously...BTW, I will try your suggestion with QOS...

Comment: In this scenario, the publisher (RPi) can use a connection less protocol such as *https*, which will be allow to publish and subscribe for the same *deviceId*. The suggestion with QOS is working well, see my article  **Azure IoT Hub Tester** on https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1173356/Azure-IoT-Hub-Tester where the M2MQTT Client library is used.

Comment: My problem that I discovered recently is that the connection code goes without errors but does not actually connect...Also, I specifically need to push data from Raspi to the cloud and read it from Win10 application running on PC/Laptop.

Comment: Again, the Azure IoT Hub is a reliable and secured bi-directional gateway between the devices and cloud back-end, so there are the **device-facing** and **service-facing endpoints**. The device can subscribed on predefined topics related for its identity only at the device side. The device (or app) can not subscribe on the topic where published it. The device messages (D2C) are pushing through routing mechanism to the default and/or custom endpoints. The default endpoint is an internal Event Hub, where are messages ingested (temporary buffered). This is a place for consuming their by your app.

Comment: For your scenario: The Raspi device is pushing data to the Azure IoT Hub and your app is consuming (reading) their from the default (built-in) Event Hub compatible endpoint. That's one direction called as a hot telemetry pipeline stream way closed to the real-time. The other way such as from cloud to device is for non-telemetry data, commands, etc.

Comment: As I mentioned above: My problem that I discovered recently is that the connection code in C# on my laptop goes without errors but does not actually connect..So my first task is to fix this. I will go through your article you referred above and will try to fix it first.

Answer (score 0):

try the following fix:

```
tpc = new string[] { 
    "devices/MasterTag/messages/devicebound/#",
    "$iothub/twin/PATCH/properties/desired/#",
    "$iothub/methods/POST/#", 
    "$iothub/twin/res/#"
    };

qosArray = new byte[] { 
    MqttMsgBase.QOS_LEVEL_AT_LEAST_ONCE, 
    MqttMsgBase.QOS_LEVEL_AT_LEAST_ONCE, 
    MqttMsgBase.QOS_LEVEL_AT_LEAST_ONCE,
    MqttMsgBase.QOS_LEVEL_AT_LEAST_ONCE
   };

var subCode = mqttClient.Subscribe(tpc, qosArray);
```

Comment: Tried the above: the results are the same - no errors/exceptions, the callback is not called. BTW, the return value is 1. And obviously no data messages received from Azure.

Comment: I think I know what's going on - despite that GUI indicator in my software says Connected I just examined the mqttClient object and IsConnected value is false. So the previous connection code is not working..